# boolean check for empty date field

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

In an MS Access 2010 database, I have the following query which works perfectly:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ordersTable.startDate, ordersTable.endDate
FROM ordersTable 
WHERE ordersTable.customerID=1 
ORDER BY ordersTable.startDate DESC;
```

How can I change the above so that it outputs a simple "YES" if endDate is empty or "NO" if endDate is not empty?

This will thereby report whether or not a given customer has a current open order.  I guess we use Iif, but I have not been able to find a good example of the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming "empty" means Null

```
SELECT TOP 1 ordersTable.startDate, ordersTable.endDate
, IIF(ordersTable.endDate Is Null, "Yes", "No") As IsEmpty
FROM ordersTable 
WHERE ordersTable.customerID=1 
ORDER BY ordersTable.startDate DESC;
```

Comment: +1 for trying to help.  But when I use your code, Access gives a dialog box saying Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression: CASE WHEN ordersTable.endDate Is Null THEN "YES" ELSE "No" End IsEmpty.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: This link says CASE WHEN can only be used in VBA: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/case.php

Comment: Ah, that wacky non-standard access! Try the edited version with IIF I don't have Access on this machine :-(